# Divisibility for natural numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that $(\forall n \in \Bbb N)(4 \mid 5^n-1 )$

I only know that if $ a \mid b \implies b =a \times q $ with $a,b,q \in \Bbb Z$

So(...)

$4\mid5^n-1 \implies 5^n-1 = 4 \times q$

But I can't prove nothing following this criteria, I'm really stuck here.

Should I apply the Arithmetic Fundamental Theorem or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: What is a linear factor of $x^n - 1$?

Comment: Binomial expansion of $(4+1)^n$?

Answer (score 3):

**Method** $1:$

$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}b+a^{n-1}b^2+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$$

**Method** $2:$

Using Binomial Theorem,
$$(a+1)^n-1=(1+a)^n-1=1+\binom n1a+\binom n2a^2+\cdots+\binom n{n-1}a^{n-1}+a^n-1$$

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*: We have $5^{n+1}-1=5(5^n-1)+4$

Answer (score 3):

The "modular arithmetic" tag gives you the hint. Congruence modulo whatever is in fact a [congruence relation](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aCongruence_Relation).

Start with the fact that $$5 \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$$

Then because congruence modulo $4$ *is* a congruence in the ring of integers,
$$5\cdot 5 \equiv 1 \cdot 1 = 1 \pmod 4.$$

Multiplying by the original again,
$$(5\cdot 5) \cdot 5 \equiv 1 \cdot 5 = 5 \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$$
etc.
Inductively,
$$5^n \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$$
so $4 \mid 5^n - 1$.

**Proof that $\equiv_n$ is a congruence:** You can easily convince yourself that it's an equivalence relation. Suppose $x,y,z\in \Bbb Z$ and $x \equiv_n y$. Then $n \mid x-y = (x+z) - (y+z)$, so $x+z \equiv_n y+z$, so $\equiv_n$ respects addition. Also, $n \mid z(x-y) = zx - zy$, so $zx \equiv_n zy$, so $\equiv_n$ respects multiplication. Picky note: It's technically necessary to show that addition and multiplication *on both sides* are respected, but the arguments are identical.

Answer (score 2):

We can prove this with induction.

For the base case, let $n=1$.  Then $4|5^1-1$.

For the inductive case, assume $4|5^n-1$.  We need to show that $4|5^{n+1}-1$.  We know that $5^n-1 = 4k$ for some $k$.  Then we have:

$$5^{n+1}-1 = 5\cdot 5^n-1$$
$$=5\cdot 5^n-5+5-1$$
$$=5\cdot (5^n-1)+5-1$$

Can you take it from here?