# Proof: Divisible by 15

Tags: proof-verification

I have to proof that $16^m - 1$ is divisible by $15$. Is my following proof correct?

$$\begin{align}
16^m - 1=&\frac{16^{m+1}}{16}-1\\
=&\frac{16^{m+1}-16}{16} \\
=&(16^{m+1}-16)\cdot\frac{1}{16} \\
=&\underbrace{(16^{m+1}-16)}\cdot\frac{1}{15(1+1/15)} \\
=&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,a\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\cdot\frac{1}{1+1/15}\cdot\frac{1}{15}\\
=&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,a\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\cdot\frac{1}{16/15}\cdot\frac{1}{15}\\
=&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,a\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\cdot\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{15}{16}\cdot\frac{1}{15}\\
=&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\underbrace{a\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\cdot\frac{15}{16}}\cdot\frac{1}{15}\\
=&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,b\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\cdot\frac{1}{15}\\
\end{align}$$
$$\therefore \boxed{16^m - 1=\frac{b}{15}}$$

Or is this the wrong way and I have to do it with mathematical induction?

Comment: You have to use induction since, apparently you can't or still haven't studied modular arithmetic (way easier).

Comment: Your approach is flawed, you've essentially shown that $b=15(16^n-1)$ exists.

Comment: This proof is not right and I explained it in my answer but, just curious, what caused you to check your proof? Why did you doubt the proof? What made you suspicious?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497235/how-to-show-that-10n-1-is-divisible-by-9

Comment: @hhsaffar : because we regularly proofed such kind of tasks in the way that we formed the expression to a multiplication e.g. a*15 and  this lead us to the fact, that a is divisable by 15. my "flawed" approach above didn't had that form and so this made me suspicious that it could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$16^{n+1}-1=16\cdot 16^n-1=15\cdot 16^n+(16^n-1)\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:Use induction and
$$16^{n+1}-1=16(16^n-1)+15$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
16^{n} - 1 = 15\,{16^{n} - 1 \over 16 - 1} = 15\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}16^{k}
$$
$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large{16^{n} - 1 \over 15} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}16^{k}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just observe that $x^n-1$ factors as $(x-1)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \cdots + x + 1)$, and make the appropriate substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have shown that there is a number $b$ that if you divide it by $15$ you will get $16^n-1$. But this does not mean that $16^n-1$ is divisible by $15$. For example $23=\frac{345}{15}$ but it does not mean that $23$ is divisible by $15$ . To show that $a$ is divisible by $b$ you have to show that $a=kb$ ($k$ is an integer, just like $a,b$)not $a=\frac kb$. Adi Dani Hinted for a solution by induction.